# Waiting for a few seconds after highlighting an element using Webdriver

Tags: java, javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to highlight an element. I want the highlight to remain for around 5-6 seconds but I'm not able to do so. 
The code for highlighting is working fine but it appears only for a flash. I tried achieving this using `thread.sleep()`, but couldn't achieve it.

Can I define a conditional wait for such highlight using `Explicit wait` or any other method.

Here is the code for highlighting the element :

```
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class HighlightElement {
public WebDriver driver;
private String baseUrl;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HighlightElement obj=new HighlightElement();
    obj.func();
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
public void func(){
driver=new FirefoxDriver();
driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

baseUrl="http://www.creativebloq.com/netmag/get-started-django-7132932";
driver.get(baseUrl);

WebElement ele=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='main-  content']/section/article/div/div/figure[1]/img"));
highlightElement(driver, ele);
try {
    Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

public void highlightElement(WebDriver driver, WebElement element) {
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);", element, "color: yellow;  border: 2px solid yellow;");
js.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);", element, "");
}}
}
```

I also tried using the sleep method within the highlighElement(), but it is also not serving the purpose.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it appears that your highlightElement function sets the element as highlighted and then immediately disables the highlighting. Try removing the last row within the loop and see if the highlighting remains

Comment: Yeah, but if I remove the last line, the element will be highlighted forever. The highlighting has to disappear after a few seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you try something like this

```
public void highlightElement(Driver, IWebElement element) 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {
            IJavaScriptExecutor js = (IJavaScriptExecutor) Driver;
            js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);", element, "color: yellow;  border: 2px solid yellow;");
            if (element.GetAttribute("style") != null)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            }
            js.ExecuteScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style', arguments[1]);", element, "");
        }
    }
```

Mine is C#. But it should not be too hard to convert and if I didn't not misunderstand your question this should work

Comment: It works. Thanks. But I was thinking more of using explicit wait.Can I somehow use that in here.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to accomplish there and how long you are trying to wait if the element is highlighted?